# How to find the distinct values in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I need distinct values from the below columns:

```
AA|BB|CC  
a@gmail.com,c@yahoo.co.in|a@gmail.com|a@gmail.com
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in,z@redhat.com|z@redhat.com
c@gmail.com|b@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in
```

Here records are '|' seperated and in the 1st column, we can two email id's which are ',' seperated. so, I want to consider that also. I want distinct email id's in the AA,BB,CC column, whether it is '|' seperated or ',' seperated.

Expected output:

```
c@yahoo.co.in|a@gmail.com|  
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|z@redhat.com  
c@gmail.com|b@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in
```

Comment: Do you have any other solution except uniq command ?

Comment: I am not getting the exact output which I want with uniq command.

Comment: Please add expected output for your example.

Comment: you have a brief snippet of expected input. Could you post what the expected output? You want uniq email address per column? but each cell might have multiple emails separated by ','?

Comment: yes Matchew, In the output I need only one delimiter either '|' or ','. I don't want the repeated email id's in the file.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the above ?

Comment: Still I didn't get the desired output. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk :

```
 cat file | tr ',' '|' | awk -F '|' '{ line=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i != "" && list[NR"@"$i] != 1){line=line $i "|"}; list[NR"@"$i]=1 }; print line}'
```

Prints :

```
a@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|z@redhat.com|
c@gmail.com|b@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in|
```

**Edit :** 
Now works properly with inputs such as :

```
a@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|a@gmail.com|
c@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in|
```

Prints :

```
a@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|a@gmail.com|
c@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in|
```

Comment: AA|BB|CC|
a@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|a@gmail.com |
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|z@redhat.com|z@redhat.com |
c@gmail.com|b@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in|
I am getting this result. here agmail.com is twice in 1st row. Could you please check it

Comment: I've tested with your sample file before posting my answer and it works fine. Have you replace `cat file` by the name of your file?

Comment: Yes. It is working. But When I insert exactly two same rows then it is not printing the 2nd row. Could you please tell me why it is happening?

Comment: This is very imp for me. The above awk script will remove duplicates from all records...not from the single line. Please Give me some solution. This script is on correct Track !!!!

Comment: Just put the below data and see whether you will get correct output or not:                                                              a@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|             y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|a@gmail.com| c@gmail.com|c@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in|

Comment: Indeed there was a bug. I've edited my answer. Sorry for coming back so late

Answer (score 3):

is awk unix enough for you?

```
{
    for(i=1; i < NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /@/) {
            mail[$i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (x in mail) {
        print mail[x], x
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ awk -F'[|,]' -f v.awk f1
2 z@redhat.com
3 a@gmail.com
1 x@yahoo.in
1 c@yahoo.co.in
1 c@gmail.com
1 y@gmail.com
1 b@yahoo.co.in
```

Comment: throwing an erroe : unexpected token '('

Comment: Thanks for not putting this on one line (as a lot of awk/sed scripts are). It really helps comprehension. While I didn't use this directly, it did help me understand what I needed to do for a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following python code will solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
while True:
    try:
        addrs = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    print '|'.join(set(addrs.replace(',', '|').split('|')))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash only:

```
while read s; do
  IFS='|,'
  for e in $s; do
    echo "$e"
  done | sort | uniq
  unset IFS
done
```

Comment: What's `$p`? Piping `echo` into the for-loop is useless.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks! These (both) are the leftovers from the answer I started to type. I later realized that to use the Bash word splitting when expanding variables does not need read (that's where `echo` and `p` (the read value) come from) at all. The answer is corrected

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this post, Hope it will work

```
while read line
    do
    val1=`echo $line|awk -F"|" '{print $1}'`
    val2=`echo $line|awk -F"|" '{print $2}'`
    val3=`echo $line|awk -F"|" '{print $3}'`


    a=`echo $line|awk -F"|" '{print $2,"|",$3}'|sed 's/'$val1'//g'`
    aa=`echo "$val1|$a"`

    b=`echo $aa|awk -F"|" '{print $1,"|",$3}'|sed 's/'$val2'//g'`
    b1=`echo $b|awk -F"|" '{print $1}'`
    b2=`echo $b|awk -F"|" '{print $2}'`
    bb=`echo "$b1|$val2|$b2"`
    c=`echo $bb|awk -F"|" '{print $1,"|",$2}'|sed 's/'$val3'//g'`
    cc=`echo "$c|$val3"|sed 's/,,/,/;s/,|/|/;s/|,/|/;s/^,//;s/ //g'`
    echo "$cc">>abcd

    done<ab.dat
```

cat abcd

```
c@yahoo.co.in||a@gmail.com
y@gmail.com|x@yahoo.in|z@redhat.com
c@gmail.com|b@yahoo.co.in|c@uix.xo.in
```

You can subtract all "," separated values and parse in the same way...if your all values are having "," separated.

Comment: It will not work: redirecting to a file will truncate it so zero size, so cat will then read an empty file.

Comment: it is working for 3 records, when we insert 4th record , the above script doesn't give the required result.

Comment: @Pooja, If you are telling about adding fourth column, than you have to add more codes.It is written for having three columns only.There should be no issue in inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, although I'm not sure what to do if there are more than three unique mails. Run with `awk -f filename.awk dataname.dat`

```
BEGIN {IFS=/[,|]/}

NF { 
    delete uniqmails; 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        uniqmails[$i] = 1;
    sep="";
    n=0;
    for (m in uniqmails) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, m;
        sep="|";
        n++;
    }
    for (;n<3;n++) printf "|";
    print ""; // EOL
}
```

There's also this "one-liner" that doesn't need awk:

```
while read line; do 
    echo $line | tr ",|" "\n"  | sort -u |\
    paste <( seq 3) - | cut -f 2 |\
    tr "\n" "|" |\
    rev | cut -c 2- | rev; 
done
```

Comment: Giving an error test_4.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test_4.sh: line 8: `echo $line | tr ",|" "\n"  | sort -u |\paste <( seq 3) - | cut -f 2 |\tr "\n" "|" |\rev | cut -c 2- | rev;  '

Comment: The one-liner requires bash (rather than sh). Therefore, you should have `!#/bin/bash` on the first line - it seems you have `#!/bin/sh`. I did not in fact put it in a file, but rather called it as `cat mails.txt | while read line; do echo $line | tr ",|" \n"  | sort -u | paste <( seq 3) - | cut -f 2 | tr "\n" "|" | rev | cut -c 2- | rev; done`

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
perl -lane '$s{$_}++ for split /[|,]/; END { print for keys %s;}' input
```

Comment: Can be made shorter with autosplit (`-a`, `-F`). "Anything can be made as Perl oneliner, which in turn can always be made shorter" :-)